# How to track Mac computer utilization throughout my organization?

Tags: macos, mac, utilization

I am looking for a way to track the utilization of 30+ Mac computers by CPU processing, network traffic, and by user. If there are other metrics that would help me determine utilization, that'd be great too, but those are the ones I could come up with.

I would like to be able to create historical reports (by week and month probably), but I have yet to find a turn key solution to this ([Rubbernet](http://rubbernetapp.com/) seems to get close, but it doesn't seem to track the historical data).

So is there a turnkey, out of the box solution for tracking utilization for Mac computers? Is it best to track this using SNMP queries and create my own solution from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried looking at netflow?

Comment: There are tons of programs that do this.  Nagios, ServiceDesk, etc...  just google

Comment: @YetiFiasco - no, but netflow seems to only track network traffic. Right?

Comment: @Keltari I've been googling, but I don't get much in terms of Mac client software to perform this kind of function. Nagios seems promising, but there is so much information, seems hard to pin point what an actual solution would look like. In fact, we have the Core of OpsView, but they don't have a Mac client so maybe just SNMP would work on that?

Comment: @wilsjd Sorry, got confused, you spelled MAC with all capitals, making me thing you meant Machine Access Code (MAC Address) rather than Mac (apple)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, [JAMF](http://www.jamfsoftware.com) makes a great product called [Casper Suite](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/) that is really simple to integrate.  It's not free and it's a **complete** systems management solution but the company is focused solely on OS X and iOS.  Even Apple sales reps are fond of saying "If Casper Suite can't do it, no one can".  If you need a full platform management solution, Casper Suite can do it but it's not free and does a lot more than what you're asking for.

And no, I do not work for JAMF.  It's just that good.

Comment: This looks really promising - I'll look into it.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the Casper Suite doesn't do historical data tracking and reporting. I will probably need to do something home brewed.